# How to export mysql schema from phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, database, export, phpmyadmin

I have a huge db that hangs the server if I try to export it, is there a way I can export it without all the data? Only the tables structure.

Comment: I come across this post as I was looking to export table structure only through phpmyadmin however I wanted to use the export as documentation so I was looking to export it in PDF with foreign key and inter table relation preserved: http://blog.cuelogic.co.in/how-to-export-mysql-database-schema-to-pdf-with-foreign-keys-and-inter/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the Export tab for your database, there's a checkbox on the lower right that says **Data**.

Uncheck it and you should only have the bare structure in your export file.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

With the newer phpmyadmin versions, in the export tab for your database or table click on custom.
[image]

Under **Format-specific options** click **dump table -> structure**
[image]

Comment: If I do two separate dumps - one for the data and one for the schema - is there a lot of overlap in terms of what gets outputted? (Logically there shouldn't be, but you can never know for sure.)

Answer (score 24):

Select your database or table.

Select the Export tab.

Below *Export method*, select Custom.

Below *Tables*, check the appropriate *Structure* boxes.

Here's a screenshot: [image]

Comment: Thanks worked for me!

Comment: this worked for me.+1

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox called "Data". Untick it and phpMyAdmin should only return the table structure.